# How to show list items on top of each other

Tags: html, css, list, navigation, html-lists

How do I show list items stacked on each other without bullet points? This Fiddle will clear things up:
http://jsfiddle.net/obliviga/6vu5q/1/

So when the user hovers over "About Us", the links that appear should be stacked on top of each other **without** bullet points, rather than be strewn across with bullet points.

I tried using `list-style: none;`, but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to put `display:block` for `li` tags then you can see the list as top of each other,

And you have a special character `&#9900` in your list's text

`<li><a href="#">&nbsp;&#9900;&nbsp;History</a>`

so remove it (if you dont want to see that as bullet point)

heres the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vu5q/2/)

Comment: if you think my answer helps you,then please mark it as answer,so other people can find it out easily,thank you